# Background image does not cover entire page

Tags: html, css, resize, whitespace, scaling

I have an extremely weird issue with a website. The background image does not cover the entire page, it creates big, white sections when I resize the window. However, it only happens on some PCs/laptops. Several friends tried the website and reported they had no issues with the image scaling and that it was constantly covering the entire page when resizing the window.

This is how it shows for me however: https://gyazo.com/04a679edfb7a442d09d6e7ce8b196cf9 feel free to check the website yourself.

I really hope someone can shed some light on whats going on. Also, the picture isnt keeping its aspect ratio, but rather zooms in/out when resizing.

https://jsfiddle.net/dn3553pg/1/

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>onepageskiw</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="forsidediv">
<img id="forsidepic" src="baggrund.jpg">
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Top</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Om Eventet</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lokation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>

<div id="logodiv">
<img src="../design/logotop.png">
</div>

<div id="overskrift">
<h1>EVENTET STARTER OM</h1>
</div>

<div id="countdowner">
<table id="table">
<tr>
<div id="countdown">
<td id="id1"></td>
<td id="id2"></td>
<td id="id3"></td>
<td id="id4"></td>
</div>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="timeLabel">DAGE</td>
<td class="timeLabel">TIMER</td>
<td class="timeLabel">MIN</td>
<td class="timeLabel">SEK</td>
</tr>
</tr>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="information">
<div>
    <h2>Hvad skal der ske?</h2>
</div>
</div>

<script>
CountDownTimer('06/25/2016 10:00 AM', 'id');

function CountDownTimer(dt, id)
{
    var end = new Date(dt);

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById(id+"1").innerHTML = days;
        document.getElementById(id+"2").innerHTML = hours;
        document.getElementById(id+"3").innerHTML = minutes;
        document.getElementById(id+"4").innerHTML = seconds;
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
}
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?             family=Montserrat:400|Raleway:100,400|);

body {
margin:0;
}

#forsidediv {
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
}

#forsidepic {
width: 100%;
}

#logodiv {
position:absolute;
text-align:center;
padding-top:15%;
}

#logodiv>img {
width:15%;
}

h1  {
font-family:raleway;
font-weight:100;
position:absolute;  
width:100%;
text-align:center;
color:white;
letter-spacing:11px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-230%);
font-size:2.5em;
}

#countdowner {
font-family:sans-serif;
color:white;
position:absolute;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
font-size:2em;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-20%);
}

#id1 {
font-size:2.5em;
}

#id2 {
font-size:2.5em;
}

#id3 {
font-size:2.5em;
}

#id4 {
font-size:2.5em;
}

.timeLabel {
font-size:0.7em;
color:#f1a01e;
font-family:montserrat;
font-weight:700;
}

#table {
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
}

#table td{
padding:0px 45px;
}

#menu {
position:absolute;
padding:0;
width:100%;
bottom:0;
text-align:center;
}

#menu>ul {
font-size:0;    
}

#menu>li {
font-size:20px;
list-style:none;
display:inline-block;
text-transform:uppercase;
letter-spacing:3px;
font-family:raleway;
font-weight:400;
}

#menu>li>a {
padding:0 15px;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
}

#menu>li>a:hover {
color:#f1a01e;
}

#information {
position:relative;
color:red;
}
```

Comment: Works/scales fine for me. That said, I'm not entirely sure why you're not using the image as a background attribute on the body tag?

Comment: See my answer below. The image will only stretch as wide as its dimension, unless you explicitly set `width: 100%`. Or ideally, use a background image instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the image as background and set it to cover the whole background like this

```
html { 
  background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick and saved me for using more IDs than needed.

Comment: @ThorKousted Could you than please accept the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the img tag in your html, set the image as a background for the "#forsidediv", or your "body" tag div with the following: background-image: url("paper.gif"); and then have it have a property of contain or strech or whatever you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Best practice here would be to set the image as a background instead and use background-size property to cover the full screen. Here's an example:

```
.image-container {
    background: url('baggrund.jpg') center center/ cover no-repeat;
}
```

To clarify why this is only happening on certain computers, it's because the image only stretches to its full dimensions but not further. So your monitor is most likely larger than your friend's. You would need to add `width: 100%` to have the image continue to stretch beyond its dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Weird part is that my laptop which is 15" and runs full-hd resolution did NOT work, and my stationary monitor which is 24" with 1900x1200 resolution did NOT work. However, a friends Macbook with 2880x1800 resolution worked perfectly. It did work for my own setup however when adding the missing width:100%.

But using background:url is easier, so thats what I did. :)